# OpenCV without display

Tags: opencv

I am running OpenCV on my Raspberry Pi 2. I want to use the GPIO instead of the display as an output indicator. However OpenCV will not run without a display.

Is there a way to fool the Raspberry Pi to run the program?

Comment: "However OpenCV will not run without a display" may i know why? Of course You can use OpenCV without Display!

Comment: can you show me any examples